# Regex matching reoccurrence of same literal

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the following values that repeat and are preceded with `:` and succeeded with `;`:

```
border-radius:5px;
border-radius:4px 4px;
border-radius:8px 8px 8px;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

The matching pattern shouldn't match the following:

```
border-radius:5px 0px;
border-radius:5px 0px 10px;
border-radius:5px 10px 8px 2px;
```

So far I know how to match everything before ':' and after ';':

```
(?<=:)(.+px)((?=;)|)
```

Also, I'm matching specific literals this way:

```
((5px)(\s)*){1,4}
```

But I want to be able to match a literal and then see if that exact same literal repeats 0 to 3 times separated with space and terminated with a semicolon.

I'm looking for something like: "If the first value is 5px then check if the following values are also 5px until a semicolon occurs."

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: I'm using the pcre engine to construct my pattern at regex101.com.  
I'll later use Sublime Text to go through a CSS file, but that doesn't matter. If for whatever reason it does match in one engine and not another I'll look for a way to adapt it to whatever regex engine I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to validate repeats:

```
:(\d+px)(?:\h+\1)*;
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN5aX8/1)

**Explanation:** (with help from OP)

`(?:\h+\1)*;` starts a new non-capturing group, `\h+` matches one or more horizontal white-spaces (such as tabs or regular space), `\1` matches the occurrence of the first capture group, it seems to do so only when the match is exactly the same value as the first capture group (so `5px` won't match with `8px` for example). Finally `*` asserts that this non-capture matching occurs `0` to infinite amount of times (so no upper limit for `4` value).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working as intended. For clarification (to other readers): `(?:\h+\1)*;` starts a new non-capturing group, `\h+` matches one or more horizontal whitespaces (such as tabs or regular space), `\1` matches the occurance of the first capture group, it seems to do so only when the match is exactly the same value as the first capture group (so 5px won't match with 8px for example). Finally `*` asserts that this non-capture matching occurs 0 to infinite amount of times (so no upper limit for 4 value).

Comment: Great explanation, I added it in answer as well.

Comment: Here is a modified pattern that uses lookaround that don't include the preceeding colon and succeeding semicolon in the matching:
`(?<=:)(\d+px)(?:\h+\1)*(?=;)`
https://regex101.com/r/zN5aX8/2

Comment: Yes that should work fine too if `:` and `;` are not to be captured

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
:\s*(\d+)\w*(?:\s+\1\w*)+;
```

Adjust the capturing group depending on your needs.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM7jZ5/1)

Comment: consider changing it to `:\s*(\d+px)\w*(?:\s+\1\w*){0,3};`

Comment: @James Buck: Thanks for the suggestion, I think there's an error with your pattern though, (\d+) would allow dissimilar values to match.

Comment: @BryceDrew: Thanks for your edit, however it does not match all required patterns: https://regex101.com/r/sQ1oH8/1

Comment: @PetrusK. `\d+` fills the initial capturing group, `\1` repeats it. Take a look at the demo I linked.